# Как правильно написать функцию события click jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Задача такая, чтобы словить клик по картинке внутри элемента. Эта картинка установлена как `backround-image` занимает определенный размер на на краю элемента, как можно перехватить событие клика именно по это части элемента?

Вот код блока

```
<span class="herd">Курьерские услуги и перевозки</span>
```

Картинка добавляется этим CSS кодом

```
   .herd {
      background-image: url(/img/select_ar2.png);
   }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получаем размер изображения и создаем блок равный размерам изображения, затем ловим по нему клик:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var image_url = $('.herd').css('background-image'),
    image;

    image_url = image_url.match(/^url\("?(.+?)"?\)$/);

    if (image_url[1]) {
        image_url = image_url[1];
        image = new Image();

        // Ждем загрузки изображения 
        $(image).load(function () {
            var bgImgWidth = image.width;
            var bgImgHeight = image.height;
            $('.herd').append('<div class="bg-button"></div>');
            $('.herd').css('position','relative');
            $('.bg-button').css({'width':bgImgWidth, 'height':bgImgHeight, 'position':'absolute','top':'0','right':'0'});
            $('.herd .bg-button').click(function(e) {
            alert('clicked');});
        });

        image.src = image_url;
    }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.herd').click(function(e) {
  alert('clicked');
  // add your code here
}
```

Подробнее: https://api.jquery.com/click/

Answer (score 2):

Событие `[on]click` происходит при *клике* на любую часть элемента. Создайте внутри элемент *img*, и отлавливайте не нем событие.